# Application changes not taking effect

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have made a change to a method used in a **Functiod** in a mapping file but it seems the new code is not taking effect, ever.

I have deployed properly, started the application, restarted related host instance (actually all host instances I could find) and still, the old code seems to execute.

Here's the, simple, method:

```
public string RemoveNonNumericChars(string stIn, int maxLength)
{
    string strOut;

    try
    {
        strOut = Regex.Replace(stIn, "[^0-9]", "");
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("BizTalk Server 2009", strOut);
        return strOut.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }
    catch
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I added the writing to EventLog line to see that this code is indeed being executed, but I don't get anything in "**Application**" event logs.

I do NOT get an empty string being returned, so it really does seem like the old code that's being executed prior to me fixing the method.

What am I missing exactly ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you shure the the right assembly is loaded? It may be getting it from somewhere else.

Comment: Well, I'm using a deploy script that worked great like 2 weeks ago. It does everything that's needed. Maybe I can post it above.

Comment: Does the deploy script log its output? There might be an indication there.

Comment: For some reason, the script is not able to correctly retrieve the Build Config selected in Visual Studio, it's taken from Debug when I'm actually trying to build it for a Test environment. I should have known, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the script is not able to correctly retrieve the Build Config selected in Visual Studio, it's taken from Debug when I'm actually trying to build it for a Test environment. I should have known, thanks anyways.